# Tracking multiple users' locations?

Tags: ios, geolocation, mapkit

Is it possible for Map Kit to track multiple users' locations like Apple does with the Find My Friends app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine:

1. Each device connects to a central service and dumps their
   coordinates in that service.
2. That service pushes (or you connect to that service and retrieve)
   the coordinates of other users using that service.

Those sets of coordinates are plotted on a map.

Voila.